# Resuming app Windows Phone

Tags: event-handling, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1

I have an app with page 1 and page 2, page 2 is instantiated only once with `NavigationCacheMode.Required`.

In page 2 I'm using the Camera so every time I navigate to other pages of the app or I suspend the app I need to dipose the Camera and reopen later.

For this reason I'm using:

```cs
Application.Current.Resuming += ResumingMethod;

private async void ResumingMethod(Object sender, Object e)
{
    Debug.WriteLine("RESUMING METHOD");
    // instantiated the Camera 
    await this.Initialize();
}
```

The navigation between Page 1 and Page 2 is working good, and I can suspend the app from page 2 and resume it without any problem. But when I navigate from Page 2 to Page 1, suspend the App and resume it, the ResumingMethod is called in Page 1, so the Camera is initialize and that's not what I what.

Is there any way to add a suspending event handler only for a page?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do something like this in your Page2 class:

```cs
public Page2()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();
    Application.Current.Resuming += Application_Resuming;
}

void Application_Resuming(object sender, object e)
{
    if (Frame.Content == this)
        createCamera();
}

protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    // This will be executed when you navigate to this page
    // but not when resuming the app from the suspended state
    // (unlike on Windows 8.1).
    createCamera();
}

protected override void OnNavigatedFrom(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    // This will be executed when you navigate away from this page
    // as well as if the application is suspended.
    disposeCamera();
}
```

---

Another way:

```cs
public Page2()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();
    this.Loaded += Page2_Loaded;
    this.Unloaded += Page2_Unloaded;
}

void Page2_Loaded(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Application.Current.Suspending += Application_Suspending;
    Application.Current.Resuming += Application_Resuming;
    createCamera();
}

void Page2_Unloaded(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Application.Current.Suspending -= Application_Suspending;
    Application.Current.Resuming -= Application_Resuming;
    disposeCamera();
}

void Application_Suspending(object sender, SuspendingEventArgs e)
{
    disposeCamera();
}

void Application_Resuming(object sender, object e)
{
    createCamera();
}
```

This way is better because you're unsubscribing from the Suspending/Resuming events when the page isn't visible.

Answer (score 2):

If you want your *Resuming/Suspending* to be specific for a page, I think you can make use of [Page.Loaded](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.frameworkelement.loaded.aspx) and [Page.Unloaded](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.frameworkelement.unloaded.aspx) events:

```cs
public BasicPage1()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();

    this.Loaded += (s, e) =>
        {
            Application.Current.Resuming += ResumingMethod;
        };

 this.Unloaded += (s, e) =>
        {
            Application.Current.Resuming -= ResumingMethod;
        };
}
```

Comment: Thanks for you help, I might use this later, but what Decade post was exactly what I needed.

Comment: I actually would've suggested this answer had I known beforehand that `Page.Unloaded` is executed when you navigate away from cached pages.

Comment: @DecadeMoon I concur that this code needs improvements, also depending on the app behavior. So do you suggest putting something inside OnNavigatedFrom? - it also has some pitfalls and is app specific.

Comment: No, what I meant was this solution is better. The reason why I went down the OnNavigatedFrom route was because I didn't realise that Page.Unloaded is executed when navigating from a *cached* page (I just assumed it didn't without testing it). The Loaded/Unloaded way is better because you have a consistent way of knowing when a Page is currently visible. The only issue is that you'd also have to handle the Suspending event too (to dispose of the camera) since Unloaded isn't executed on suspension (unlike OnNavigatedFrom).

Comment: @DecadeMoon I only answered the question 'Is there a way...', you are right that camera disposal needs some more attention. I like your new edit (+1) as it doesn't use OnNavigatedFrom (you solved my problem when the event is not fired when suspending). I'm only not sure what happens when you navigate forward - is unloaded fired? Have you debuted it?

Comment: @Romanz Loaded is fired when you navigate to that page by any means. Unloaded is fired when you navigate away from that page by any means (forward or backward). Specifically, Loaded is fired when the frame adds the page element to its content, and Unloaded is fired when the frame removes the page element from its content and then it adds the next page to its content (this is true for any FrameworkElement). NavigationCacheMode has no effect on when Loaded/Unloaded is called; caching the page merely keeps the page instance in memory and will reuse it the next time that page is navigated to.